# How to draw an arrow to a table cell?

Tags: tables, arrows

I'd like to draw something like [drawing an arrow to a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9592/drawing-an-arrow-to-a-table-cell). But in my case the arrow should be in the right side. Could you please change the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{5mm}}r@{\hspace{5mm}}r@{\hspace{5mm}}r@{\hspace{5mm}}r}
      \toprule
      &      & a & b & c \\
      \midrule
      0      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
      0      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
      0      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
      0      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
        \noalign{\smash{\llap{\lower2pt\hbox{$\longleftarrow$}}}}
      0      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
      0      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/9043) I removed the thanks. This is just the style here. Thanks is best expressed by upvoting answers that help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{5mm}}r@{\hspace{5mm}}r@{\hspace{5mm}}r@{\hspace{5mm}}r}
      \toprule
      &      & a & b & c \\
      \midrule
      0      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
      0      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
      0      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
      0      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\rlap{~\lower4pt\hbox{$\longleftarrow$}}\\
      0      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
      0      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]