# Pointing from Data in a pgfplotstable to a pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Are there PGF coordinates available for elements in a [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) table? Groupplots allow to address plots via `(group c2r1.center)` (column 2, row1).

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=&,row sep=\\,sci zerofill]{
  colA & colB & colC \\
  11   & 12   & 13   \\
  21   & 22   & 23   \\
}
```

With such coordinates I could draw an arrow from data in a pgfplotstable to its representation in a plot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not out of the box, because all `pgfplotstable` does is typeset a normal `tabular`. You can make `\pgfplotstabletypeset` wrap the cell contents in TikZ nodes, however, similar to what is done by hand in the  answer to [How to draw lines around multiple table cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9442/how-to-draw-lines-around-multiple-table-cells/9448#9448).

Below is the code including an example of how to use it. It redefines the cell contents of the tables generated with `\pgfplotstabletypeset` to contain nodes with the naming scheme `<table name>-<row>-<col>`, which is the same scheme also used by TikZ `matrix` command.

Note this needs two compile runs to position everything correctly, which is always the case when using TikZ' `remember picture` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

% Define new column and row counters
\newcounter{colcount}
\newcounter{rowcount}

% Command for wrapping cell contents in TikZ nodes with name <table name>-<row>-<col>
% 'remember picture' is necessary to make the node positions available in other tikzpicture environments
\newcommand\tabnode[1]{%
  \addtocounter{colcount}{1}%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline,inner sep=0pt]
    \node (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/name}-\arabic{rowcount}-\arabic{colcount}) {#1};
}

% New key for referencing tables typeset with pgfplotstabletypeset
\pgfplotstableset{name/.initial={table}}
% Redefine the typeset code to call \tabnode and reset counters as needed
\pgfplotstableset{
  typeset cell/.code={
  \ifnum\pgfplotstablecol=\pgfplotstablecols
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\tabnode{#1}
      \addtocounter{rowcount}{1}
      \setcounter{colcount}{0}\\
    }%
  \else
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\tabnode{#1}&}%
  \fi
}
}


% Example of use: Read table and save to a macro.
% This step is not necessary, you could also provide the table inline to \pgfplotstabletypeset
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&,row sep=\\]{
  colA & colB & colC & Column D \\
  11   & 12   & 13  & 9 \\
  21   & 22   & 23  & 15 \\
  17 & 10 & 19 & 20 \\
}\mytable


\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
% Typeset the table as usual.
% You can provide an optional name, otherwise the nodes will be called tab-<row>-<col>
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=&,row sep=\\,sci zerofill,name=table]\mytable
\end{minipage}%
\hfill %
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
% Plot the data. 'clip=false' stops the path being clipped at the axis boundary
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\begin{axis}[clip=false,width=5cm]
\addplot table \mytable;
% Draw a connection line. Needs the 'overlay' option
\draw[overlay,red] (table-2-2) -- (axis cs:21,22);
\draw[overlay,red] (table-3-2) -- (axis cs:17,10);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: drawing lines between table and plot]