# Table with a diagonal line that crosses cells

Tags: tables

How can I draw the following table in LaTeX?

[image]

I tried looking [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjgxunnsPTMAhVIoZQKHeT5DuIQFgg0MAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikibooks.org%2Fwiki%2FLaTeX%2FTables&usg=AFQjCNGX22yhQ92bv4z9ptOY0sLHXbvdAA&bvm=bv.122676328,d.dGo) but from the examples I can't figure out how I can draw this.

**Edit:** After browsing a few more times I found [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwihwrigsPTMAhXLmZQKHb2bAFYQFghBMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tablesgenerator.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNExOak16-QBgxdfe7Ndm2BxMyqFjg) with the help of which I could draw the table *without the diagonal*. Here is my MWE,

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{CONCEPT} & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{COMPREHENSIVE NOTES}                                \\ \hline
Man                            & Substance & Material & Living           &     Sentient & Rational & Man \\ \hline
Animal                         & Substance & Material & Living           &     Sentient & Brutes   & Man \\ \hline
Organism                       & Substance & Material & Inanimate Bodies &     Plants   & Brutes   & Man \\ \hline
Body                           & Substance & Material & Inanimate Bodies &     Plants   & Brutes   & Man \\ \hline
Substance                      & Substance & Spirit   & Inanimate Bodies &     Plants   & Brutes   & Man \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}         & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{EXTENSIVE SUBJECTS}                                 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Should the diagonal be reproduced too?

Comment: @Mico: Yes. It should be.

Comment: Do these links help ?
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17745/diagonal-lines-in-table-cell

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7262/diagonally-divided-table-cell

Comment: or you could use something like this to draw over your table ?
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9442/how-to-draw-lines-around-multiple-table-cells

Comment: @EladDen: I can't figure out how to use them to fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With tikz

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2][]{\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\node[#1,inner sep=0pt,xshift=-\tabcolsep](#2){};\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\tm}[2][]{\tikzmark[yshift=#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{CONCEPT}& \multicolumn{6}{c|}{COMPREHENSIVE NOTES}                                                       \\ \hline
Man                          & Substance & Material               & Living           & Sentient & Rational &\tm[1.8ex]{A} Man \\ \hline
Animal                       & Substance & Material               & Living           & Sentient & Brutes   & Man              \\ \hline
Organism                     & Substance & Material               & Inanimate Bodies & Plants   & Brutes   & Man              \\ \hline
Body                         & Substance & Material               & Inanimate Bodies & Plants   & Brutes   & Man              \\ \hline
Substance                    & Substance & \tm[-0.9ex]{B} Spirits & Inanimate Bodies & Plants   & Brutes   & Man              \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}       & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{EXTENSIVE SUBJECTS}                                                        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\draw[thick] (A)--(B);
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Better answer than mine because you are able to just set your `\tm` in any cell in the table and the line gets drawn programatically.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way of doing it, using the `graphicx` package:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{CONCEPT} & \multicolumn{6}{c|}%
{COMPREHENSIVE NOTES\Large\strut}                                \\ \hline
        Man                            & Substance & Material & Living           &     Sentient & Rational & Man \\ \hline
        Animal                         & Substance & Material & Living           &     Sentient & Brutes   & Man \\ \hline
        Organism                       & Substance & Material & Inanimate Bodies &     Plants   & Brutes   & Man \\ \hline
        Body                           & Substance & Material & Inanimate Bodies &     Plants   & Brutes   & Man \\ \hline
        Substance                      & Substance & Spirit   & Inanimate Bodies &     Plants   & Brutes   & Man \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}         & \multicolumn{6}{c|}%
{EXTENSIVE SUBJECTS\Large\strut}                                 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}


\vskip-1.17in\rotatebox{14}{\hskip1.5in\vtop{\hsize=3.75in\rule{3.28in}{1pt}}}



\end{table}
```

and adjust the dimensions to fit your needs. I added a `\Large\strut` to adjust the cell padding for the top and bottom cells.

[image]

Comment: Try doing it in TikZ, since this would allow it to stretch with the content.

Comment: I'm sure that somebody will.  I'm surprised there is not already a tikz solution.

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar to `{tabular}` (of `array`) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells. Then it's possible to use those nodes with Tikz to draw whatever rule you want (in the `\CodeAfter` or in the `\CodeBefore` of the array).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lllllll}[hvlines]
\multicolumn{1}{c}{CONCEPT} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{COMPREHENSIVE NOTES}                                    \\ 
Man                            & Substance & Material & Living           &     Sentient & Rational & Man \\ 
Animal                         & Substance & Material & Living           &     Sentient & Brutes   & Man \\ 
Organism                       & Substance & Material & Inanimate Bodies &     Plants   & Brutes   & Man \\ 
Body                           & Substance & Material & Inanimate Bodies &     Plants   & Brutes   & Man \\ 
Substance                      & Substance & Spirit   & Inanimate Bodies &     Plants   & Brutes   & Man \\ 
                               & \multicolumn{6}{c}{EXTENSIVE SUBJECTS}                                  \\ 
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw (2-|7) -- (7-|3) ;
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]